Play audio from Docker container
On my MacBook (Sonoma 14.6.1), I've got a Python script that uses pyaudio (which uses portaudio) to play audio files through my speaker.  The script works just fine.  However, for reasons, I'd like to run the script inside of a Docker container (Ubuntu 22.04).  When I run my script that way, I get
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_id returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM dmix

I'm guessing this has something to do with the container being unable to locate the audio device.  Is there an option I can pass to docker run to mount the device?
UPDATE:
I followed the instructions given in this SO answer but still received no sound output.  I did, however, see some logs from the pulseaudio daemon:
AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:2356  --> setPlayState Started Output {410C0FC2-0000-0000-0A22-010380462778, 0xa}
AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:2379  Devices are same: =0. Previous: {()}. Current: {("410C0FC2-0000-0000-0A22-010380462778")}
AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:981   Sent updated IOState to server: [0, 1]. BT device UIDS: {()}
AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:2397  <-- setPlayState Server update was required.
AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:2356  --> setPlayState Stopped Output {410C0FC2-0000-0000-0A22-010380462778, 0xa}
AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:2379  Devices are same: =0. Previous: {("410C0FC2-0000-0000-0A22-010380462778")}. Current: {()}
AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:981   Sent updated IOState to server: [0, 0]. BT device UIDS: {()}
AVAudioSession_MacOS.mm:2397  <-- setPlayState Server update was required.

I tried playing a .wav file from the container with paplay.  The command succeeded (and took the right amount of time for the length of the .wav file) but there was no output.  The corresponding pulseaudio logs were
I: [] client.c: Created 0 "Native client (TCP/IP client from 127.0.0.1:52371)"
I: [] sink-input.c: Trying to change sample spec
I: [] remap.c: Using mono to stereo remapping
I: [] speex.c: Choosing speex quality setting 1.
I: [] sink-input.c: Created input 0 "sample-1728359287.wav" on Channel_1__Channel_2 with sample spec s16le 1ch 44100Hz and channel map mono
I: [] sink-input.c:     media.format = "WAV (Microsoft)"
I: [] sink-input.c:     application.name = "paplay"
I: [] sink-input.c:     media.name = "sample-1728359287.wav"
I: [] sink-input.c:     native-protocol.peer = "TCP/IP client from 127.0.0.1:52371"
I: [] sink-input.c:     native-protocol.version = "35"
I: [] sink-input.c:     application.process.id = "40"
I: [] sink-input.c:     application.process.user = "user"
I: [] sink-input.c:     application.process.host = "02a5f943ef9c"
I: [] sink-input.c:     application.process.binary = "pacat"
I: [] sink-input.c:     application.language = "C"
I: [] sink-input.c:     application.process.machine_id = "02a5f943ef9c"
I: [] sink-input.c:     module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:paplay"
I: [] protocol-native.c: Requested tlength=2000.00 ms, minreq=20.00 ms
I: [] protocol-native.c: Final latency 2250.00 ms = 1960.00 ms + 2*20.00 ms + 250.00 ms
I: [] sink-input.c: Freeing input 0 "sample-1728359287.wav"
I: [] client.c: Freed 0 "paplay"
I: [] protocol-native.c: Connection died.


Perhaps this SO answer is worth checking for your needs? Or https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/running-a-docker-soundbox-on-mac.html

Hm, no good.  I did exactly as that SO answer recommends and I get the same error.
